# написал код где пайтон должен искать файл где есть такие слова

Tags: python

```
import os, glob, fitz, docx

findword = input("ведіть слово")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("files"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf = fitz.open(filename)
            for current_page in range(len(pdf)):
                page = pdf.load_page(current_page)

                if page.search_for(findword) or page.search_for(findword.upper()):
                    print("найшлось в pdf file " + filename)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk("files"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            txt = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
            if findword in txt or findword.upper() in txt:
                print("найшлось в txt file" + filename)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/38068/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/вшкусе.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, glob, fitz, docx
  File "C:\Users\38068\lib\site-packages\fitz\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from frontend import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend'
```

Comment: код нормально отформатируй. нечитаемо

Comment: поздравляю! вопрос где?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Молодец, что написал. Напиши ещё какой нибудь код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467667/how-do-i-resolve-no-module-named-frontend-error-message